# Authentication in KSOAP2 request to .NET webservice in Android

Tags: android, .net, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I am trying to access a secure .NET SOAP webservice in an Android app, using the KSOAP2 library. I have checked for other answers on Stack Overflow, but so far none of them have helped me.

A username and password are required for authentication. The method also takes a String and returns a complex type. I have gotten this to work with an identical but unsecure service (ie, no username/password, but passing String and returning complex type works fine).

I can connect to the secure webservice using soapUI. All I have to do is give it the correct String parameter, set the username and password through the SoapUI request properties, and also set the WSS-PasswordType to "PasswordText".

I am confused about how to achieve this through my Java code. The SoapUI request (which works) looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>(my username) </wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">(my password) </wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">eic5EdyTomcBLocwyph5Mw==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2012-02-08T09:47:55.225Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetClientByNationalID>
          <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:nationalID>(the nationalID) </tem:nationalID>
      </tem:GetClientByNationalID>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I figured I should be passing username and password in the Soap header then so I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613675/how-to-set-soap-header-using-ksoap2-android) but this didn't work. I then used [Lalit's answer] ([SOAP web service on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564467/soap-wev-service-on-android)) below to edit the header of my request to try to make it identical to the SoapUI-generated request, but I am still getting the same error. Here is what my code is now producing:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header>
    <n0:Security mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:n0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <n0:UsernameToken n1:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:n1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <n0:Username>(my username)</n0:Username>
            <n0:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">(mypassword)</n0:Password>
            <n0:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">eic5EdyTomcBLocwyph5Mw==</n0:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2012-02-08T09:47:55.225Z</wsu:Created>
        </n0:UsernameToken>
    </n0:Security>
</v:Header>
<v:Body>
    <GetClientByNationalID xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
        <nationalID i:type="d:string">(testnationalID)</nationalID>
    </GetClientByNationalID>
</v:Body>
```

This is the error I'm still getting in LogCat:

```
02-10 10:53:49.261: W/System.err(1187): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path
not found.
```

This makes it look like a certificate issue, so I imported the cert from the server with InstallCert and verified with Keytool that it's in my keystore. This made no difference. On the other hand, I assume it's not a certificate issue since SoapUI worked before I had that cert installed.

Now I'm confused, so here are my questions:

1) Is adding the cert to the cacerts keystore in my JRE lib/security enough, or do I need to write some Java code to then access this cert?

2) Is this a cert issue at all, if SoapUI was able to connect successfully to the webservice without me installing the cert?

3) If it's not a cert issue, can anyone advise on what kind of code I need to use to produce a Soap request that will successfully authenticate and then execute the method call? I presume this is a case of getting my java-produced request to look as similar as possible to the SoapUI-generated request.

Comment: have you check these links [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441158/how-can-i-access-an-ssl-connection-through-android), [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection)

Comment: I am not sure if those links apply when I am using KSOAP2 - do I still need to set up my SSL connection manually?

Comment: @breadbin Hi, how did you added that <wsse:Security headers? i want to form the request like this. http://pastebin.com/HPYJ8N9e. can u please guide me how to add the usernametoken authentication in soap request for android

Answer (score 4):

You can create the `Header` element and add the `Authentication` details,

```
Element[] header = new Element[1];
header[0] = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE,"AuthHeader");
```

**Add Username tag with username,**

```
Element username = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "username_tag");
username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "username_value");
header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);
```

**Add Password tag with password,**

```
Element password = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "password_tag");
password.addChild(Node.TEXT, "password_value");
header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, password);
```

**Add the header to the** `SoapSerializationEnvelope`

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope
                                                                         .VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.headerOut = header;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

Comment: I tried this and still get the same error. What about this line:   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">(my password)</wsse:Password> ?
I know that if I don't set the WSS-PasswordType to "PasswordText" then it doesn't work, so I imagine I need to do this in Java code somehow. Do you know how?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564467/soap-wev-service-on-android) answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Lalit Poptani, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I have updated my java-generated request above to show what I'm now producing, and it still isn't working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, not much idea about it.

Comment: @LalitPoptani I am getting this error In my webservice :

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions name='hubbuchUser' targetNamespace='http://elofizetes.eszak.hu/soap/hubbuch/'>@4:98 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4205c058)

Comment: Lalit Poptani: This is my web api link [http://182.19.20.182:81/mcommerce.webservices/pgService?wsdl](http://182.19.20.182:81/mcommerce.webservices/pgService?wsdl)  can you tell me what  is my AuthHeader name?

Comment: @LalitPoptani you saved my life. After a lot of things tried, this is the only thing that has worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late. Please have a look at the answer on the following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17691465/2499764

I can share the code for constructing the header if you are still interested.

Comment: Too late for me, but thanks for your answer anyway. I hope it helps someone else.