# Calling .NET webservice with ksoap2 in Android , no result returned

Tags: android, .net, ksoap2

i have been trying to call a simple .NET webservice (HelloWorld) via android using ksoap2 ( i already tried and succeeded for a different webservice) . but this one requires an authentication so i searched how to add a header for the authentication , but still , i have no result returned in my textview.

```
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);  
List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic"+Base64.encode("Username:Password".getBytes())));


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


        try{
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope,headers);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

            tv.setText("yo :" + resultString);

        }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also an error in my Log :

> ERROR : Thread Attached failed , but i don' think it's the source of

here is the wsdl for the HelloWorld method :

> 

```
>     <wsdl:types>
>     <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
>     <s:element name="HelloWorld">
>     <s:complexType/>
>     </s:element>
>     <s:element name="HelloWorldResponse">
>     <s:complexType>
>     <s:sequence>
>     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HelloWorldResult" type="s:string"/>
>     </s:sequence>
>     </s:complexType>
>     </s:element>
```

> my problem.
>   Have anyone encountered this kind of problem , or my code is wrong at some point ?

Comment: if the .net ws method is have any paramenter? that is request

Comment: i don't think so ,it's just a Helloworld testing , so i didn't add property to my request

Comment: i add some code if you need use it...I hope that will be help to you..

Comment: Hope this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564467/soap-wev-service-on-android/3879616#3879616

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);    
request.addProperty("requst_name",request_value);//if you have any request add here..                   
 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
 envelope.implicitTypes = true;
 envelope1.dotNet = true;
 int Timeout = 60000;
 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, Timeout);
 androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                try {

                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    Object response = envelope.getResponse();
                    String res=response.toString();
                    }

                    }catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: i tried your code , but no result either , no exceptioon caught , it seems that the code is fine , but my textview doesn't display the result . i tried to set my textview to test it inside me try catch block: tv.setText("yo :"); and it still display just textview when i launch the app , what does it mean ?

Comment: can you post your wsdl file

Comment: Okey , i add it to my question

Comment: have you print this  String res=response.toString();?

Comment: in mine no , but when i used your code i did .
how can u explain that even when i set : tv.setText("yo :") it wasn't displayed , it's like the try catch block is ignored !

Comment: used this code System.out.println("Result: "+res); after this line String res=response.toString();

Comment: Nothing about res is diplayed in the console !

Comment: Object response = envelope.getResponse(); replace this line into SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

Comment: can u give me your email so i can send you this ? ( cause u'll need my login and password )

Comment: couldn't fint it . anyway here is the details
http://demo.digiparc.com/autocomplete.asmx
login : mLabraiki
pass: 123456

Comment: I used some logs , apperntely the problem is in this line : aht.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
i catched an exeption too : 
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@45f9a5d0)

Answer (score 0):

.This  is how I access .net web service. In my case i am sending 2 parameters username and password , where the service will return a string according to the database.If you are not passing any parameters please remove the parameters I have mentioned and add only this

```
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);
```

---

else

```
 public String Call(String username, String password) {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
            OPERATION_NAME);

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("username");
    pi.setValue(username);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("password");
    pi.setValue(password);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    Object response = null;

    try {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();
    }

    catch (Exception exception) {
        response = exception.toString();
    }

    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: My webservice doesn't require parametres ( at least for the HelloWrold Method) but it requires authentication before accessing it